# Missing Value in the form?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Whenever I try to create a new table with this...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(300) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`password` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
`activation` varchar(300) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
)
```

I get a pop up that says. `Missing value in the form!`. I've tried looking for answers, but most of them say to disable Ajax, which I cannot do. I've also tried different browsers and nothing seems to work.  I'm using `phpMyAdmin 4.1.6`

Comment: `varchar` must have no more than 255 character, and you set is 300 character

Comment: Fixed. Thank you. Consider adding an answer. @dhidy

Comment: please vote my answer below.

Comment: Where within phpMyAdmin are you getting this message? I just tried from the SQL tab within a database and it didn't give me the error you described. If you can help me reproduce the error, we can try to improve how phpMyAdmin handles the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

varchar must have no more than 255 character, and you set is 300 character

look at this ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html )